# Determine a self-balanced binary tree height formula knowing its number of node

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

I have been working on determining the height of a self-balanced binary tree knowing its number of nodes(N) and I came with the formula:

> height = ceilling[log2(N+1)], where ceilling[x] is the smallest integer not less than x.

The thing is I can't find this formula on the internet and it seems pretty accurate.

- Is there any case of self-balanced binary tree this formula would fail?
- What would be the general formula to determine the height of the tree then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a formula on Wikipedia's [Self-balancing binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) article.

```
h >= ceilling(log2(n+1) - 1) >= floor(log2(n))
```

The minimum height is `floor(log2(n))`.  It's worth noting, however, that

> the simplest algorithms for BST item insertion may yield a tree with height n in rather common situations. For example, when the items are inserted in sorted key order, the tree degenerates into a linked list with n nodes.

So, your formula is not far off from the "good approximation" formula (just off by 1), but there can be a pretty wide range between `n` and `log2(n)` to take into account.

Comment: Thank you. The difference I see between wikipedia formula and mine is root node is at level 0 while mine is at level 1. I prefer their formula though.